# TypeScript как правильно убрать ошибки?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Подскажите, как убрать ошибку, которая нависла над этой строчкой

```
selected.value.push(el)

Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.Vetur(2345)
const el: any
const el: any
```

?

Только начал разбираться в TypeScript

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, useStore, ref } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const parentCategories = ref([])
    const categories = ref([])
    const selected = ref([])

    const store = useStore()

    categories.value = store.getters.GET_CATEGORIES

    parentCategories.value = getParentCategories()

    const changeCategory = (id: Number) => {
      const el: any = categories.value.find((el: any) => el.id === id)

      if (!el) return false

      const children = categories.value.filter(
        (item: any) => item.parentId === el.id
      )

      if (children.length > 0) {
        parentCategories.value = categories.value.filter(
          (item: any) => item.parentId === el.id
        )
        selected.value.push(el)
      } else {
        store.dispatch('SET_CATEGORY_MODAL_SELECTED', el)
        closeModal()
      }
    }

    const prevCategory = (id: Number) => {
      const categorySelected: any = categories.value.find(
        (el: any) => el.id === id
      )

      if (!categorySelected) return false

      if (categorySelected.parentId === 0) {
        parentCategories.value = getParentCategories()
        selected.value = []
      } else {
        parentCategories.value = categories.value.filter(
          (item: any) => item.id === categorySelected.parentId
        )
      }
    }

    const closeModal = () => {
      store.dispatch('OPEN_CATEGORY_MODAL', false)
    }

    function getParentCategories() {
      return categories.value.filter((item: any) => item.parentId === 0)
    }

    return {
      closeModal,
      changeCategory,
      prevCategory,
      selected,
      parentCategories,
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Comment: Руки бы отрубить за `any`) А так, скорее всего из-за того, что у Вас `selected` без типа, и TS пытается привести его к `any`, а не к `any[]`

Comment: а как правильно нужно писать?)

Comment: Ну точно не any))) У Вас типизация для чего вводится? Для того, чтобы огромный болт на неё положить? Указывайте конкретные типы, которые будут принадлежать переменным